# How get the src value from the img clicked

Tags: jquery, image, get, click, src

I would get the src value of an img clicked. I have this HTML  https://jsfiddle.net/4k541boj/`code`

```
 <span id="sinistra">
        <img src="http://www.bicielettriche.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/bici-elettrica-piaggio.png">
        <img src="https://eradellabicicletta.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/bici-da-corsa-rb1000-team-edition.jpg">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9ty91M-QHPrgy6woAJAgdF68UrTD8c91WXz5dfznU1R_2GQ5Qjw">
        </span>

$('#sinistra img').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

But i don't understand where i'm wrong.
can someone help me?

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: you forget to include Jquery file :). check my ans :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        // Listen for clicks to "img" elements inside the element where id="sinistra"
        $("#sinistra img").click(function () {
          // Displays the source of the image clicked
          alert($(this).attr("src"));
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="sinistra">
      <img
        src="http://www.bicielettriche.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/bici-elettrica-piaggio.png"
      />
      <img
        src="https://eradellabicicletta.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/bici-da-corsa-rb1000-team-edition.jpg"
      />
      <img
        src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9ty91M-QHPrgy6woAJAgdF68UrTD8c91WXz5dfznU1R_2GQ5Qjw"
      />
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jsFiddle works fine, but you have to add the jQuery library, clicking on the word javascript with the gear and selecting jQuery in the "Frameworks & extensions" input.

But your code is right.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the problem was the missing line `code`$(document).ready(function () {

Answer (score 0):

Is Jquery is Included in your page.From the fiddler link which you have provided it's pretty clear that Jquery is not included as 'uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined' error is coming

Comment: thanks for the answer, the problem was the missing line `code`$(document).ready(function () {